# In VS Code, I can't install GitHub extension

Tags: github

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu2CX.png)

how can i install git hub in vs code?

At First, I thought Git hub is integrated in VS Code.
But, When i input git command in 'cmd' there's no output.

I want to know how i can use git command in VS code.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things you need to do before using Git in vscode

**Install Git:**

1: If you haven't installed Git on your Windows system, you can download the Git installer from the official website: https://git-scm.com/downloads

2: During the Git installation process, you'll come across an option titled "Adjusting your PATH environment."
Choose the option "Git from the command line and also from 3rd-party software." This will ensure that Git is added to the $PATH variable during installation.

3: Complete the installation process.

Verify Git installation:

Open a new command prompt or terminal window. Type git --version and press Enter. If Git is properly added to the $PATH variable, you should see the version of Git installed on your system.

**installing Extension:**

Install `GitHub Pull Requests and Issues` from within VS Code or download it from the marketplace.

and then all you need to do is open a git projects folder and then the menu will pop up